# Android creating a filename path from user input

Tags: java, android, file

I'm sure there is a simple answer to this but I'm new and can't seem to figure this out.

I need to save data to a text file. I have all the code to do that but the path and filename is hard-coded for now. I have an EditText field where the user enters the filename and then hits a button. I want it to create a path and filename based on what the user enters.

Basically a pre determined path of "/sdcard/"+Whateveruserentered.txt

Comment: Just get the value of whatever the use enters in the `EditText` you set up, turn it into a string and use the `+` operator to add it to file pathname.

`EditText filename = new EditText(this);
        filename.getText().toString();`

Answer (score 1):

Ok , here is a simple answer,

suppose you have entered "myPath/myfile.txt" in EditText,

First you need to create "myPath" folder ( I am assuming you are giving foldername too in path ).

```
String fullPath = myEditText.getText().toString().trim();
String folderPath = fullPath.substring ( 0, fullPath.indexOf ( "/" ) );
String fileName = fullPath.substring ( fullPath.indexOf ( "/" ) + 1 );

// First Create folder by coding, 

File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + folderPath );
if (!folder.exists()) 
{
      folder.mkdirs();
}

// Note: your path must not have recursive folders like myPath1/myPath2/myFile.txt, otherwise you need to create folder in 2 steps.

// Now creating file
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + folderPath + fileName );

if ( !file.exists() )
{
    success = file.createFile();
}

// Now your file is created, you can do writing code now onwards.
```

Comment: Awesome! I already had the path defined but what worked was using your first line and changing it to my needs: String filename =edittextfield.getText().toString().trim();    Thank you so much!