# File is created with no data is written to it

Tags: android, file-io, outputstream

I tried to create a text file and write data to it using the code shown below:

JAVA CODE_1:

```
File dir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File file = new File(dir,"/DCIM/"+fileTitle);

    try {           
        if( file.exists() ){
        FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(fileTitle, MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
        OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fos);
        osw.write("this is a text");
        osw.flush();
        osw.close();
        } else {
            file.createNewFile();
            FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(fileTitle, MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
            OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fos);
            osw.write("this is a text");
            osw.flush();
            osw.close();
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

But when I check the DCIM directory, I find that the file is created but no data is written to it. please tell me where my mistake is.

Comment: try out my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12417282/996493)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, Its not created on **External Storage** but its created on **Application's Internal Storage**,
(Check your file is created on `/data/data/<Application_Package_Name>/files` directory)

Because,

you are using  `openFileOutput` which one creates file in Application's Internal storage.

```
public abstract FileOutputStream openFileOutput (String name, int mode)
```

Since: API Level 1

Open a private file associated with this Context's application package for writing. Creates the file if it doesn't already exist.

**Code:**

```
file.createNewFile();
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file, true);
OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fos);
osw.write("this is a text");
osw.flush();
osw.close();
```

Comment: but the file exists under ../DCIM/ directory..and i dnt have a pth such the one u posted in my device

Comment: Look in **adb shell**... you got the File Path and File. Also its available on **DCIM** folder because you are creating empty file using this code line `file.createNewFile();`

Comment: but sorry for inconvenience, i dont know how to check the path u posted..i dont have such path

Comment: or at least please let me know how to create a text file under DCIM correctly and add data to that file

Comment: i changed it to fos = FileOutPutStream(fileTitle,MOODE_WORLD_READABLE); but eclipse underline the fileoutputstream with red

Comment: i did what did u suggest but still eclipse undlines it with red

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5374379/impossible-to-create-file-on-external-storage-android and my updated answer.

Comment: i think the example show what i had done in the beginning the user define os as an object of FileOutputStream the assign this object os to OpebFileOutput

Comment: concerning the updated code there is no errors but still the file is empty

Comment: Your else part code is not executed... Create other file with different name and only use the code which I mentioned.. nothing else..

Comment: i created other file with different name and it's just created with no data inside it

Answer (score 0):

Use only

```
        FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(fileTitle, MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
        OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fos);
        osw.write("this is a text");
        osw.flush();
        osw.close();
```

It will create file in internal storage.

Or use

```
        File dir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File file = new File(dir,"/DCIM/"+fileTitle);
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
        OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fos);
        osw.write("this is a text");
        osw.flush();
        osw.close();
```

Comment: the first code snippet i have already used it and it just create the file and no data is written to it. concerningthe 2nd code snippet eclipse underlines FileOutputStream with red

Comment: concerningthe 2nd code there is no errors but still the file is empty